# Array values into separate strings

Tags: php

I've an array

> Array (
>       [0] => value1
>       [1] => value2
>       [2] => value3
>       [(n)] => .....)

I want this as following:

```
  $string1 = 'value1';
  $string2 = 'value2';
  $string3 = 'value3';
  $string(n) = '....';
```

Please suggest the right way to get this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this rather than simply using the array as it is?

Comment: If you absolutely have to do this, then [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) with a `prefix` argument of `"string"`

Comment: why? you're searching for `extract`

Comment: I  need this for set of string to be used in a query as like condition.

Comment: No you don't, you can build the query using an array..... there's no need to split it all into separate variables

Comment: In Yii query for where ('field like :field',array(':field'=>$array)). In this scenario array is failed to process

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

```
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "string");
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hcubrO)**

Comment: The option needed is `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` and you will obtain: `$string_0 = 'value1'`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for what you need?

```
foreach($array as $key => $row) {
    $var = "string" . $key;
    $$var = $row;
}
```

But you said you need to do a query with the values. Maybe something like this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 = 1";
foreach($array as $key => $row) {
    $sql .= " AND string" . $key . " = '" . $row . "'";
}
```